# One question open and one closed. Why?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

The two following questions are quite similar, yet one is closed and the other remained open. What is the reasoning behind this? Is there something that I do not see?

[How to reply to “You're going to hell”? [closed]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/75416/25495)

[Is there an appropriate response to “Jesus Loves You”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74332/25495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## HYPOCRISY!

I seem to be on the receiving end of the benefit of the doubt for once?

---

No, I think my question (the "Jesus Loves You one")  is on topic because it's about Protestant customs, the "You're going to Hell" one is pastoral advice.  It's a fine line, and if the OP on the closed question would describe the circumstances it'd be OK.  Furthermore, I put a lot of thought into how I could make it on topic.  My original idea for the question was probably a lot like the closed one, but I knew it would be off topic so I tried to make it more concrete.

I'd imagine there's a difference between a Jehovah's Witness and a Swedenborgian and a Westboro Baptist telling me that I'm going to Hell.

Comment: My assessment as well.

Answer (score 0):

The questions are similar in form but actually quite different. One question asks about cultural traditions, the other for advice on how to act in awkward and difficult situations. If someone tells you "Jesus loves you" there's a general response of "thanks/he loves you too". But if someone tells you you're going to hell, Christians don't even agree whether you should respond, let alone what kind of response to make.

The other question isn't great either IMO, and I've given it a close vote for being philosophical/sociological.